# How can we use SortedMap Interface for sorting a Map?

Tags: java, collections, sortedmap

I have `UnsortedMap<String, CustomObject>.` Here key, though of String type stores numeric values.

Though there are many ways to sort a Map but i want to do sorting using SortedMap interface.

Is there any way to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `SortedMap` doesn't sort, it indicates that the `Map` implementation is sorted (ie it has some total ordering).

Comment: Thanks Mark... Actually that is my confusion. So its the treeMap for sorting and not SortedMap Interface.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question, because that is not what you are asking in your question (or at least: that is not how I read it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), specifically **All Known Implementing Classes**.

Using [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is probably not bad in your case:

```
SortedMap<String,CustomObject> map = new TreeMap<String,CustomObject>();
map.putAll( yourUnsortedMap );
```

On a side note, if you know your keys to be numeric, why not have the Map be of erasure `<Integer,CustomObject>` instead?

Cheers,

Comment: We can do this also :                         Map<String,CustomObject> map = new TreeMap<String,CustomObject>(); Then also we get sorted map.then why there is sortedMap interface

Comment: @Prateek Look at the api doc of [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) it has additional methods that only make sense when the implementation has an order.